# Where can I find reports of accidents/incindents happened on ground?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, airport

**What international organization or website has the information on this topic?**

I’m looking for reports, statistics and analyses of incidents and accidents (other than those involving aircraft) that occurred at work locations of an airline, airport, or handling agent involving passenger handling service departments with customer service facilitating passengers and baggage, i.e., ticketing and reservations, check-in counters, immigration control, duty free shops or other concessionaires, boarding gates, jetways or aircraft steps, shuttle bus for boarding or arriving, aircraft parking bays, baggage claim areas, baggage conveyor belts, and other such locations.

ICAO, IATA and ACI have the stats but they're all aircraft related only.

Comment: [to the downvoters, try to at least leave a comment to help a newcomer help understand]

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It looks like you want to get statistics of incidents/accidents of all kinds in the limits of an extended airport area (extended because work locations of an airline are usually close to an airport, but not in the airport). And that worldwide. I'm afraid such completeness is not possible, e.g. shuttle bus collisions and duty free shop floodings are not registered using any standards, and maybe there are no requirements for that at all. To help you edit your question, you may want to use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

If you're excluding aviation safety incidents (those that relate directly to the safe operation of an aircraft), then I am pretty confident in saying that there is no single international source of the information you're seeking.

Those stats will probably be held by insurance companies, and the workplace safety authority of the country or state where the airport is located.

Comment: Apart from anything else, what workplace (non-aviation) accidents are reportable differs from state to state. Even when the stats are held, they might only relate to staff and not customers. And of course they won't include most accidents that don't cause any personal injury.